# How can i detect audio level of a stream or tcplistener or the audio card using C#

Tags: c#, .net, audio, directsound

Is this possible using only C#?  I want to be able to detect audio from: a stream, microphone or soundcard and begin recording if audio level is above a settable threshold.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this using [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com). Have a look at the [.NET Voice Recorder](http://voicerecorder.codeplex.com) application for an example of detecting the input level. To detect audio from a stream, you would need to create a class derived from WaveStream and override its Read method to return the data from your TcpListener